# Using of NStimer to set image animation with default image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nstimer, icarousel

How to integrate two images where one act as default and another as animating image when app launches..The animating image should not come again even that view loads again..it should come only when app launches like default.png image..The idea is to get two default images..How can i do that?..

Here is my code...

```
@interface ViewController ()<UIActionSheetDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL useButtons;

@end

@implementation ViewController

 @synthesize carousel,Chaintop;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel              ;

CGRect ChaintopFrame = Chaintop.frame;
ChaintopFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;    

[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                  Chaintop.frame = ChaintopFrame;
                     //Chainbottom.frame = ChainbottomFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
   [self.view addSubview: Chaintop];
   }


 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
[super viewDidUnload];
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

    - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
   return NUMBER_OF_ITEMS;
      }

  - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
  {

   UIImage *buttonImage=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_0.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_3.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_4.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_5.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_6.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_7.png"],nil];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f);

[button setImage:(UIImage*)[buttonImage objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;



 }

 -(void)dealloc{
[Chaintop release];

 }



 - (BOOL)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel shouldSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
   {
if (index == carousel.currentItemIndex)
{
    NSLog(@"Should select current item");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Should select item number %i", index);
}
return YES;
  }

  - (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
  {
if (index == carousel.currentItemIndex)
{
    //note, this will only ever happen if useButtons == NO
    //otherwise the button intercepts the tap event
    NSLog(@"Did select current item");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Did select item number %i", index);
}
     }
     @end
```

Comment: I have already told you, put it in the app delegate, you splash screen or image then with timer for the next image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `APP DELEGATE`.
Something like this should do the job:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NAMEOFYOURSPLASHSCREEN.png"];
    imageView.image = image;
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self performSelector:@selector(remove1stSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:5];
    return YES;
}

- (void)remove1stSplash:(UIImageView *)1stView {
    UIImageView *imageView = ...
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(remove2ndSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:5];
    [1stView removeFromSuperView];
}

- (void)remove2ndSplash:(UIImageView *)2ndView {
    [self.window addSubview:.....
    [2ndView removeFromSuperView];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Link for a sample project:
[Two Splash Screen display in iphone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/two-splash-screen-display-in-iphone/)

Comment: remove the Default.png the implement this.

Comment: this is just an imageView, it will show your first image then after that another image